# Como autentico un usuario luego del registro, sin redireccionar al login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Apenas estoy empezando a conocer estos temas de spring security, y no he logrado logear un usuario justo después de registrarlo, a pesar de que lo he intentado de varias formas.

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public String signup(@ModelAttribute User user ) throws Exception {
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

    userService.save(user);

    
    UserDetails userDetails = detailService.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
    
    System.out.println("Usuario autenticado: " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

    return "redirect:/articles";
}
```

Este es el controlador de ejemplo y una de las maneras que no me resulto, a pesar de que en el controlador se imprime el usuario que acabo de asignar al contexto de spring, cuando este se redirecciona a la ruta indicada el usuario autenticado vuelve a ser anonymousUser.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authRequest ->
                authRequest
                  .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/createArticle")).authenticated()
                  .anyRequest().permitAll()
                  )
                .formLogin(form->form.loginPage("/login").permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/articles"))
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                .logout(out ->
                out.logoutRequestMatcher(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/logout"))
                        .permitAll()
                        )
                .build();
            
            
    }

    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```